# I bought a new car for a month and wanted to return it

Tags: credit, car, auto-loan

Here is my story. I bought a car about six weeks ago on march. I realized that I was actually paying a lot more than the price in the car advertisement.

I bought a Honda Odyssey 2016 that is supposed to be around $32000, but I have to pay $699 monthly for 72 months and the total will be $50400. Will I be able to return the car? If so, what should I be expecting? I was going to ask a lawyer, but a lawyer could be costly.

Comment: What is your interest rate?

Comment: His interest rate is probably around 16.xx considering the payments/interest, but 6 weeks using a car is a long time to consider. I suspect the ability to return the car for a refund is long past.

Comment: can you refinance?

Comment: say i successfully return my car what do you think will happened, do i pay the interest of 15000??

Comment: Forget returning the car. There is no return policy

Comment: You could try to sell it to the car dealer. Don't expect to get full price back. Consider this an expensive lesson.

Answer (score 8):

My assumption here is that you paid nearly 32K, but also financed about 2500 in taxes/fees.  At 13.5% the numbers come out pretty close.  Close enough for discussion.

On the positive side, you see the foolishness of your decision however you probably signed a paper that stated the true cost of the car loan.  The truth in lending documents clearly state, in bold numbers, that you would pay nearly 15K in interest.  If you pay the loan back early, or make larger principle payments that number can be greatly reduced.

On top of the interest charge you will also suffer depreciation of the car.  If someone offered you 31K for the car, you be pretty lucky to get it.  If you keep it for 4 years you will probably lose about 40% of the value, about 13K.

This is why it is foolish for most people to purchase a new vehicle.  Not many have enough wealth to absorb a loss of this size.  In the book *A Millionaire Next Door* the author debunks the assumption that most millionaires drive new cars.  They tend to drive cars that are pretty standard and a couple of years old.  They pay cash for their cars.

The bottom line is you singed documents indicating that you knew exactly what you were getting into.  Failing any other circumstances the car is yours.  Talking to a lawyer would probably confirm this.

You can attempt to sell it and minimize your losses, or you can pay off the loan early so you are not suffering from finance charges.

Comment: i am not sure by pay the loan back early?? are you saying that i should pay the 15000 interest??

Comment: @needhelp: he meant that you need to pay it back sooner than 72 months. That is, instead of 699/mo pay 1500/mo, or something.

Comment: Good idea mentioning the "Truth in Lending" agreement. It breaks out a cost for each individual item, including financing charges.

Answer (score 7):

Following up on @petebelford's answer:

If you can find a less expensive loan, you can refinance the car and reduce the total interest you pay that way.

Or, if your loan permits it (not all do; talk to the bank which holds the loan and,/or read the paperwork you didn't look at), you may be able to make additional payments to reduce the principal of the loan, which will reduce the amount and duration of the loan and could significantly reduce the total interest paid ... at the cost of requiring you pay more each month, or pay an additional sum up front.

Returning the car is not an option. A new car loses a large portion of its value the moment you drive it off the dealer's lot and it ceases to be a "new" car. You can't return it. You can sell it as a recent model used car, but you will lose money on the deal so even if you use that to pay down the loan you will still owe the bank money. Given the pain involved that way, you might as well keep the car and just try to refinance or pay it off.

Next time, read and understand ***all*** the paperwork before signing.

(If you had decided this was a mistake within 3 days of buying, you might have been able to take advantage of "cooling down period" laws to cancel the contract, if such laws exist in your area. A month later is much too late.)

Comment: Usually "cooling down" doesn't apply to *new* cars, only used (and then - only when bought from a dealer, not a private party).

Comment: I think it's broader in some US states. In any case, the querant is long past any reasonable second-thoughts period; they clearly accepted the deal they were offered, and there is no extended warranty against "buyer's remorse".